# Docker compose .env file array variable

Tags: arrays, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im using docker-compose, and Im using env file with my local variables.
I need to pass array variable.
I have tried:

```
TAGS="12345","67890"
```

or

```
TAGS=["12345","67890"]
```

or

```
TAGS=("12345" "67890")
```

Im getting always error:

```
List(WrongType(STRING,Set(LIST, OBJECT),Some(ConfigValueLocation(file:/src/target/scala-2.12/classes/application.conf,86))
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: There is no array type support for `docker-compose.yml`, you might want to add it as a comma-separated-string, and explode it to different elements as a comma (using a bash script).

Answer (score 18):

As [Confidence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099972/confidence) mentioned above, write a comma separated string:

```
TAGS=12345,67890
```

Then in your application (Python for instance):

```
os.getenv('TAGS').split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Boot Framework, this can be achieved with the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` property:

```
services:
  my-app:
    image: my-app:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={
          "TAGS":[12345,67890]
        }
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: dont you needs some thing like `- |` or `- >` to make the multiline work?

Comment: No, i wondered myself too, but this works as is in my docker-compose.yml. Everything else didn't work, like beginning `'` or `"`. I have this currently running. (With subobjects in the array).